# Can´t change the navigation bar in master study theme

Tags: wordpress

i have installed the wordpress master study theme (demo import distance learning). Sadly i cannot change the navigation bar on the left side as the screenshot shows. Do you know how I can remove it or change it? Is this from elementor or wordpress native?

Best
dontknowguy

[image]